# Regex assert that string contains numbers in order

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string `number1\nnumber2\nnumber3` is it way to assert that 1, 2 & 3 are in order using regex?

examples
valid string `number1\nLetter2\nnumber3`
`number1number2\nnumber3`

example invalid string
`number2\nnumber1\nnumber3`
`number1\nnumber2\nnumber3\nnumber1`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [ask]. In particular, please post the things you've tried already

Comment: `/1[^1]*2[^12]*3[^123]*$/`

Comment: So how many items in the sequence? is it fixed?

Comment: @Pac0: counter example `"1.3.2.3"` expected `false`, actual `true`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko thanks, I changed beginning to `1[^13]`

Comment: `^\D*1\D*2\D*3\D*$` ?

Comment: `var result = Regex
        .Matches(source, "[0-9]+")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(match => match.Value.TrimStart('0'))
        .SequenceEqual(new string[] { "1", "2", "3"});`

Comment: Does it *have* to be a single regex to do the entire check, or would it be sufficient to extract the numbers with a regex, then parse them as numbers and check they are increasing order?

Comment: This question lacks sufficient information to answer unambiguously. however my money is on @DmitryBychenko style answer

Comment: @Tobbax If people ask extra questions, the expectation is that you answer them. Otherwise people are going to have a hard time putting an answer together, and your question will be closed as "Needs more details". If this happens, you can edit it and ask for it to be re-opened, but it will have dropped off the front page and won't get the same level of attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For numbers 1 2 and 3, this should do the trick:

`1[^13]*2[^12]*3[^123]*$`
or
`1[^123]*2[^123]*3[^123]*$`

Edit: if you may have other numbers in your strings, which makes this invalid in any case, you should even go for:

`^\D*1\D*2\D*3\D*$` (1, 2, and 3 should be in this order, without any number anywhere else)

You can test here, it matches your correct and doesn't match incorrect examples properly.

http://regexstorm.net/tester

Comment: I think it’s more clear to write `[^123]` for all of them, but that might just be me.

Comment: @Ry- I'd say it's a matter of taste, I see your point

Comment: This matches `1.2.5.3`. It's unclear from the question whether that's valid

Comment: @canton7 good point, alternatively use `\D` to get rid of them completely, as I just noticed that is in your answer.

Comment: Technically, `"3.2.1.2.3"` returns `true`, but it's unclear if such string is valid or not

Comment: That matches `999.1.2.3`. Again, not sure whether that's valid. I assumed not, but until/unless OP chimes in, that's anyone's guess

Answer (score 1):

If the question is interpreted as:

1. Anything which isn't a number
2. Followed by `1`
3. Followed by anything which isn't a number
4. Followed by `2`
5. Followed by anything which isn't a number
6. Followed by `3`
7. Followed by anything which isn't a number

Then you can write this as:

```regex
^\D*1\D*2\D*3\D*$
```

This matches strings such as:

```
1.2.3
test1.2.3
1.2.3test
```

It does not match:

```
999.1.2.3
1.2.999.3
1.2.3.999
```